# Google Apps Script. Cannot set value in range because number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Task was to find word 'Request' in a specific range (**variable "range"**), copy information from nearest column on rows which match 'Request', then paste it to another range.

Cannot figure out how to insert value of **variable "offsetval1"** in multiple cells. Seems like it returns 9 values, but if I check using **Logger.log(offsetval1.length);** it returns **1.0.** However, there are 9 rows with different values (check screenshot).

How to input values of **"offsetval1"** in range with these 9 rows?

```js
function DocReq() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please, enter Line Count"); // Prompt Input
  var line_count = result.getResponseText(); // Prompt Result (Number) as VAR
  var int_line_count = (+line_count); // Number as Integer
  var range_bottom = int_line_count-1; // Integer - 1 (Total Amount of Rows)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var currect_cell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow(); // Row of Active Cell
  var int_current_cell = (+currect_cell); // Row as Integer (Top First Row)

  var main_range_bottom = int_current_cell+range_bottom; // Bottom Last Row
 
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('L' + int_current_cell + ':' + 'L'+ main_range_bottom); // Get Range All !Requested!

  var find_rqst = range.createTextFinder('Requested').findAll(); // Creating Text Finder !Requested!

  for (var i = 0; i < find_rqst.length; i++) { // Finding Exceptionally !Requested!
    var arrayofreq = find_rqst[i];

    var offsetval1 = arrayofreq.offset(0, -4).getValues(); // Getting Values of !H! Column of All !Requested!
    Logger.log(offsetval1);
    }
    Logger.log(offsetval1.length);
    Logger.log(find_rqst.length);

  spreadsheet.getRange('K131:K139').setValues(offsetval1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue:

The issue with the code is that `offsetval1` is defined iteratively inside the `for` loop and therefore it always contains one value, this is why the length is `1`. You are actually overwrite the previous content with the new one.

- Try to store each value to an array and then `set` the array instead.

### Solution:

```
function DocReq() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please, enter Line Count"); // Prompt Input
  var line_count = result.getResponseText(); // Prompt Result (Number) as VAR
  var int_line_count = (+line_count); // Number as Integer
  var range_bottom = int_line_count-1; // Integer - 1 (Total Amount of Rows)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var currect_cell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getRow(); // Row of Active Cell
  var int_current_cell = (+currect_cell); // Row as Integer (Top First Row)

  var main_range_bottom = int_current_cell+range_bottom; // Bottom Last Row
 
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange('L' + int_current_cell + ':' + 'L'+ main_range_bottom); // Get Range All !Requested!

  var find_rqst = range.createTextFinder('Requested').findAll(); // Creating Text Finder !Requested!
  var offsetval1 = []; // Modified code

  for (var i = 0; i < find_rqst.length; i++) { // Finding Exceptionally !Requested!
    var arrayofreq = find_rqst[i];
    offsetval1.push([arrayofreq.offset(0, -4).getValue()]); // Modified code
    }

  spreadsheet.getRange('K131:K139').setValues(offsetval1);
}
```